# If $ A\ \Delta \ B=(A\ ∪\ B)-(B\ ∩\ A)$ prove $A\ \Delta \ B = (A-B)\ \cup \ (B-A) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is correct this proof ?

$A\ \Delta \ B=(A\ ∪\ B)-(B\ ∩\ A)$

\begin{split}
x \in (A \ \cup B)- (B\ ∩\ A)  & \Rightarrow x\in A  \ \cup B\  \wedge x \notin A\ \cap \ B\ \\
 & \Rightarrow (x \in A\ \vee x\in B) \wedge\ x\notin A\ \cap \ B\   \\ & \Rightarrow (x \in A \ \wedge x\notin A\cap B ) \ \vee \ (x \in B \ \wedge \ x\notin A\ \cap B\ )\\ &\Rightarrow (x \in A \ \wedge x\notin  B ) \ \vee \ (x \in B \ \wedge \ x\notin A) \\&\Rightarrow\ x\in  \boldsymbol{(A-B)\ \cup \ (B-A)}
\end{split}

---

Second part

$ x \in (A-B) \cup \ (B-A) \Rightarrow x\in (A - B)\ \vee x \in (B- A)$

\begin{split}
x\in (A - B) & \Rightarrow x \in A\ \wedge x\notin B\\ & \Rightarrow x \in A \cup B \ \wedge x\notin B  \\ &\Rightarrow x \in A \cup B \ \wedge x\notin  A
 \cap B \  \\&\Rightarrow\ x\in  \boldsymbol{(A\cup B)\ - \ (A\cap B)}
\end{split}

Comment: No, it is not correct.  You have only proved half.  Next you need to do the other direction.  Or check that all those $\Rightarrow$ can be made into $\Leftrightarrow$.

Comment: Now it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, but (was) incomplete; you need(ed) to prove the reverse inclusion. Just replace all your implications (in your first half) with biconditionals.

Comment: OP's work is correct, but the proof is incomplete, namely the reverse inclusion has not yet been shown.

Comment: Well spotted, @KevinLong. I've edited it now.

Comment: Now it is correct?

Comment: Yes, @Daniel. ${}$

Comment: Thank you @Shaun and KevingLong :D Can you give me a hint to prove if $A \Delta B=\emptyset$ then $A \subset B$ or $B\subset A$ please ?

Comment: You're welcome, @Daniel. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick! Also, just draw the Venn diagram; it'll guide you! Use the identity you've just proven.

Comment: Ask a separate question, @Daniel, and be sure to include what you've tried so far.